# JIRA SOAP Client - return invalid field value

Tags: soap, client, jira

I have a problem using JIRA SOAP client. When I use RemoteIssue.getResolution() or RemoteIssue.getStatus() I get number values. For example let say we have an issue that has resolution = fixed. When I call client.getIssueFromJqlSearch(token, "issuetype = Bug AND resolution = fixed", 10) this will return an array of type RemoteIssue[]. Now if I call issues[i].getResolution() (where issues[] is the result from previous call getIssuesFromJqlSearch) this will return a value "5" instead of "fixed". How to solve this? Is there any way to get the value "fixed" for that issue and not a custom value "5"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What version of JIRA are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call getResolutions() on the SOAP API you'll get an array of all the resolutions defined in the instance, including their Ids. You can then use this to work out which resolution the Id you've got refers to.